# Searching for how many times a word appears in a text file in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and pointers, so it is still confusing as hell! Below is the code of a function with the main purpose of finding how many times a word appears on a text file. Any help will be appreciated!

```
void count_occurrences (int n, FILE *file, Entry *entries) {
    file = fopen("test/flicka.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        char buff[LINE_MAX_CHARS];
        int i = 0;
        char * haystack = fgets(buff, 1000, file);
        char * needle = NULL;
        char * p = NULL;
        while (haystack != NULL) {
            for (i; i < n; i++) {
                needle = entries[i].string;
                while ( (p = strstr(haystack, needle)) != NULL) {
                    entries[i].count++;
                    p++;
                }    
            }
            haystack = fgets(buff, 1000, file);
            i = 0;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else {
        printf("File not found!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep searching the same haystack over and over.  You need to skip over the haystack that's already been searched.  Your `p++;` should be `haystack = p + 1;` so as to move the search on one space.  This allows "aaa" to match "aaaaa" 3 times; if you only want it to match once, then `haystack = p + strlen(needle);`, except you can calculate `strlen(needle)` once outside the loops.

Comment: Also note that you either pass an already open `FILE *` into the function, or you use a local variable `FILE *file` and open and close the file in the function.  You don't pass a `FILE *file` into the function and then ignore it by opening a file.  Granted, it doesn't hurt the copy of the `FILE *` in the calling code, but it is pointless.  (And it would probably be better to pass the name of the file as a parameter (`const char *filename`) than to hard-wire it as shown.  All else apart, you can then report which file name in the error message without repeating yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for your help Jonathan. How can you open the file in the function using the pointer given as an argument (FILE *file)?

Comment: Succinctly, you can't.  Either the function should be given an already open file stream (`FILE *`) which it reads to EOF (but does not close), or it should be given a file name (`const char *`) in which case it opens, reads and closes the file.  Either approach is feasible.  I'd probably go with the 'pass an open file stream' as it is more flexible (it can process standard input; that's harder with the other design), but the alternative also works. (With the 'pass an open file stream' approach, there'd also be a separate function to open a named file, call the function, and close the file.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with an exercise like this is that the best way of solving the specific problem - a character-based state machine attached to the stream - doesn't scale up to larger problems.

To do it first way, you maintain a "parse position" which is initially zero. You then call fgetc() in a loop until data runs out and you get EOF. If the character matches the character at the parse position, increment the parse position, if the parse position goes to the end of the string, you have a match, so increment the count. If it doesn't, reset the parse position to zero or one depending on whether the first character matches.

The first way is fast and easy, but inflexible.

A more scaleable way is on line-based input. Call fgets with a big buffer if you know lines must be short, or build a "getline" if lines are unbounded. Then call strstr on the line to see if you have a match. If you have a match, you need to increment the pointer and check for another.

The scaleable way separates the parse from the IO and allows you to search for multiple patterns. Pseudo-code

```
while(line = getline() )
{
   N += countwords(line, "myword");
}

int countwords(line, word)
{
   ptr = line;
   while(strstr(ptr, word))
   {
     ptr = strstr(ptr, word) + strlen(word); // replace strlen with 1 to allow overlaps 
    answer++; 
   }
}
```

Obviously you now need to modify the main loop to search for several words, keeping an array of Ns and calling repeated with each word. But it scales up to any sort of pattern matching.